# Creating a database and putting it on a server through ftp

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, ftp, raspberry-pi

I have webspace that I can access through ftp. I need a database that I can read and write to remoteley. Is there any way to put a database on a server when the only way I can access that server is through an FTP username and password? I would like to be able to send data from a raspberry pi to this database, then display the data on my website.

Comment: how would you manage this DB, if all that you have is ftp?  How do you start, stop, add data, query data etc through ftp?

Answer (score 0):

There is not one database in the world that you can access the data via FTP directly. FTP is a  file transport protocol and most database use their own protocol to communicate with remote users.

For example Microsoft SQL server uses the `TDS` protocol. MySQL will have its own protocol etc. Another problem you will have is that FTP is extremely insecure. Your user name and password will be hacked if you use this protocol. DO NOT use FTP to transfer sensitive data.

The only way you will be able to let the Raspberry Pi send data to the database is to program it to talk the MySQL protocol. Or to send up a file via FTP and then upload this file with scripts.